# After rejecting a suggested edit and cancelling, I can't continue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click Reject

   [image: Reject]
2. Click the X in the corner to close the reject window

   [image: the X in the corner]
3. This happens forever (until a refresh)

   [image: Rejecting...]

   3a. Also, I see a JS error:

   [image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null]

I'm using Chrome 31.0.1650.48, on Windows 7.

The same problem occurs when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but clicking outside of the popup box does not seem to cause this issue.

Comment: ah, thanks @MartijnPieters, apparantly my search-fu is not good enough :P

Comment: I only found it because I knew I had just reviewed a close vote for an earlier dupe to the same question.

Comment: I found it because I had remembered this issue being raised a few hours ago. Alas, even _that_ was a dupe.

Comment: Once you've closed that door, you can't go back. I know, weak. But I've not finished my first cup of caffeine, yet.